# The element 'product.info.options' already has a child with alias 'text' - Magento 2.2.0

Tags: cart, addtocart, magento2.2, data-migration

After data migration (1.9.1 CE - 2.2.0 CE) I got the below error when I click add to cart button in magento 2

> we can't add this item to your shopping cart right now

I did research about this but found no clue...

**log says :**

> The element 'product.info.options' already has a child with alias 'text' {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): The element 'product.info.options' already has a child with alias 'text' at /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Data/Structure.php:611)"} []

Comment: in my case, the custom theme was overriding layout XML file with all the child blocks inside the parent block. I removed all the child blocks from the theme XML. It resolved the issue. Please check if any of custom theme files has redeclaration of child blocks.

Comment: Hi Prathap Gunasekaran, Do you fix this issue?